# perl DBI connect to mysql database without password

Tags: mysql, perl, database-connection, dbi

I would like to use DBI to connect to a mysql database as user mysql, but without password. Is this possible?

Example:

```
#create database, grant access to mysql
mysql -e 'create database perltest; grant all on perltest.* to mysql@localhost'
```

my perl code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use DBI;

$dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:mysql:perltest','mysql', NULL)
    or die "Connection Error: $DBI::errstr\n";
```

So the third argument for `DBI->connect` is the password. In all examples I have seen, a password is used. I tried various things as the third argument: `NULL`, `null`, `''`, `' '` etc., but every time it is interpreted as a password. Any ideas?

Comment: `$dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:perltest","mysql",undef,{ RaiseError 
+=> 1 });` ?

Comment: Works, thanks. Could have figured that out by myself, new to perl...

Comment: updated the answer with more info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just use `undef`:

`$dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:perltest","mysql",undef,{ RaiseError => 1 });`

UPD. btw, [this fiddle](https://eval.in/101727) is probably helpful explanation of how perl operates with all this null/0/undefined stuff. Got original code from [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=326544)

Comment: @mpapec mistype. fixed.